# Returning two Result-Sets with only one statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

The SP somehow returns a second result set when executed and I just don't know why.
Anyone have an idea?

This is the Code

```
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE SP_CURRENT_USER 

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * FROM Verify where UserName = (CAST(CURRENT_USER AS nvarchar(max)));

END
GO
```

Comment: how is the procedure called ?

Comment: I executed it test-wise in my SQL-Server (2014 I think) manually by clicking "Execute Stored Procedure".

Comment: Just run "EXEC SP_CURRENT_USER" in a new SQL Query and let us know of the result.
This procedure as I see should return only one dataset...

Comment: Then you got the result set and the return value of the stored procedure. You did not get two result sets!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When calling the procedure using the `"Execute Stored Procedure"` you will see that the generated script for that is similiar to this:

```
USE [DBName]
GO
    DECLARE @return_value int
    EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[SP_CURRENT_USER]
    SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

And what you will see will be the `result set` from your select query and the `"Return Value"` from the stored procedure itself. In your case it should be 0, which means that the execution terminated successfully.

Please refer to this article "[Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)" to get to know some possible issues with naming your procedures `"sp_"`.